# Not able to load BHO when IE is opened as non admin in EPM mode

Tags: 64-bit, internet-explorer-10, bho, visual-c++-2010

I have created 64 bit BHO which I am trying to load in windows 8 IE10.
I am trying to open IE in user account with non admin privileges.
BHO gets loaded when I open IE as Administrator(by right click on it and click Run as admin)

But same BHO is not getting loaded by IE when I open it in non admin mode.

Are there any registry changes I need to make so as to get it loaded when IE is opened as non admin.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, running IE as admin seems to lift any restrictions enforced by EPM.

EPM requires that your BHO is compiled for x64 and x86, and that your BHO registers itself as AppContainer compliant.
If you're using an RGS file to define your BHO's class, you should add:

```
'Implemented Categories' = s ''
    {
        {59fb2056-d625-48d0-a944-1a85b5ab2640} = s ''   
            {
            }
    }
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570827/ie-bho-in-epm-enhanced-protected-mode) for more details.

Also your BHO's DLLs should be in an AppContainer readable folder (I know by experience that subfolders of "Program Files" and "System32" are AppContainer readable).