# How to make my IE10 toolbar compatible with IE11 on Windows 8.1?

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, winapi

I've an Internet Explorer Toolbar written in Delphi 7 (using COM) that works fine in IE 8-10 and IE 11 on Windows 7. But in IE11 + Windows 8.1 it's automatically disabled with an error message that it's not compatible. It cannot be re-enabled until the Enhanced Protected Mode is disabled in IE.

Googling I've found this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It says that IE 11 Addons on Win 8.1 need to include an "AppContainer compatible flag", but it provides no info how to do it.

What Delphi Code do I need to add to my toolbar, so it contains the AppContainer compatible flag?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570827/ie-bho-in-epm-enhanced-protected-mode

Comment: After much research I think it's impossible without a 64bit version, meaning at least Delphi XE4.