# Win 10 IE 11 - Cannot Get a Simple BHO To Run Under 'Enhanced Protection Mode'

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I am trying to get a test BHO to run in IE 11 - Win 10 in "Enhanced Protection Mode".

All the BHO does is fire an alert, 'hello world'.

I have built the library using 'Any CPU'.

I made sure I wrote to the registry and made it writeable (see full class further down the page):

```
var registryKey =
            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, true);

        if (registryKey == null)
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(
                                    BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default);
```

I have placed the library in a sub directory of Program Files.

I have run a .bat file that registers the library using x32 and x64 Regasm.

When that didn't work another option I tried was building the library exclusively for x32 and another for x64. Then registering both.

I have spend hours researching this (I have read every post here that looked remotely related) and I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

To be fair the workable solutions I have found here are for Win 8 and Win 7. To be clear I am unable to get this to work on 'Win 10' environment. I CAN get the same code to work on 'Win 7' environment (I don't have Win 8).

I am desperate, any help would be appreciated!!

Install.bat for the Any CPU library:

```
@echo off

:: Register

SET SYSPATH=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\V4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe

%SYSPATH%  "%~dp0\IEExtension.dll"  /unregister

%SYSPATH%  "%~dp0\IEExtension.dll"  /codebase 

SET SYSPATH=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\V4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe

%SYSPATH%  "%~dp0\IEExtension.dll"  /unregister 

%SYSPATH%  "%~dp0\IEExtension.dll"  /codebase

pause
```

The test bho extension code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using mshtml;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using SHDocVw;

namespace TestExtension
{ 
    /* define the IObjectWithSite interface which the BHO class will implement.
        * The IObjectWithSite interface provides simple objects with a lightweight siting mechanism     (lighter than IOleObject).
        * Often, an object must communicate directly with a container site that is managing the object. 
        * Outside of IOleObject::SetClientSite, there is no generic means through which an object     becomes aware of its site. 
        * The IObjectWithSite interface provides a siting mechanism. This interface should only be used     when IOleObject is not already in use.
        * By using IObjectWithSite, a container can pass the IUnknown pointer of its site to the object     through SetSite. 
        * Callers can also get the latest site passed to SetSite by using GetSite.
        */
    [
        ComVisible(true),
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
        Guid("FC4801A3-2BA9-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352")
    // Never EVER change this UUID!! It allows this BHO to find IE and attach to it
    ]
    public interface IObjectWithSite
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetSite([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]object site);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite);
    }

    /* The BHO site is the COM interface used to establish a communication.
        * Define a GUID attribute for your BHO as it will be used later on during
        * registration / installation
        */
    [
            ComVisible(true),
            Guid("3295D3BF-AEB3-4F89-96BC-8A83723B1388"),
            ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)
    ]
    public class TestBHO : TestExtension.IObjectWithSite
    {
        private WebBrowser webBrowser;
        public const string BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME =
                "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\" +
                "CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";
        /* The SetSite() method is where the BHO is initialized and where you would perform all
            * the tasks that happen only once.
            * When you navigate to a URL with Internet Explorer, you should wait for a couple of events to make
            * sure the required document has been completely downloaded and then initialized. Only at this point
            * can you safely access its content through the exposed object model, if any. This means you need to
            * acquire a couple of pointers. The first one is the pointer to IWebBrowser2, the interface that
            * renders the WebBrowser object. The second pointer relates to events.
            * This module must register as an event listener with the browser in order to receive the
            * notification of downloads and document-specific events.
            */
        public int SetSite(object site)
        {
            if (site != null)
            {
                webBrowser = (WebBrowser)site;
                webBrowser.DocumentComplete +=
                    new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(
                    this.OnDocumentComplete);
            }
            else
            {
                webBrowser.DocumentComplete -=
                    new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(
                    this.OnDocumentComplete);
                webBrowser = null;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite)
        {
            var punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(webBrowser);
            var hr = Marshal.QueryInterface(punk, ref guid, out ppvSite);
            Marshal.Release(punk);
            return hr;
        }

        public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
        {
            var document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;

                var head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)
                                    document.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);

            var scriptObject =
                (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
            scriptObject.type = @"text/javascript";
            scriptObject.text = "alert('Hello World');"; // <---- JAVASCRIPT INJECTION HAPPENS HERE!

            ((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);

        }

            /* The Register method simply tells IE which is the GUID of your extension so that it could be loaded.
            * The "No Explorer" value simply says that we don't want to be loaded by Windows Explorer.
            */
        [ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void RegisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            var registryKey =
                Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, true);

            if (registryKey == null)
                registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(
                                    BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default);

            var guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
            var ourKey = registryKey?.OpenSubKey(guid, true);

            if (ourKey == null)
            {
                ourKey = registryKey?.CreateSubKey(guid, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default);
            }

            ourKey?.SetValue("NoExplorer", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            registryKey?.Close();
            ourKey?.Close();
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        public static void UnregisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            var registryKey =
                Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, true);
            var guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

            if (registryKey != null)
                registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: With AppContainer is turned on, IE11 checks the add-on registration for an AppContainer compatible flag. If it's present, the BHO or toolbar loads and runs. If it isn't present, the BHO or toolbar is blocked, and the user is notified of the EPM incompatibility. Ref:https://github.com/CognizantQAHub/Cognizant-Intelligent-Test-Scripter-IE-Toolbar/issues/9 I did not get any information specifically for Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would do that?

Comment: You can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570827/ie-bho-in-epm-enhanced-protected-mode