# IE11 compatible addon

Tags: internet-explorer-11, compatibility, add-on

I have to write an IE11 addon and I found some good sources for start but I always got stuck in the compatibile issue. Turning off of EPM is not allowed and we tried to enabled our prototype addon in GP ([Using the CLSID and Administrative Templates to manage group policy objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enable-and-disable-add-ons-using-administrative-templates-and-group-policy)) but the situation is the same.
I would like to know how I can write a compatible addon because I found nothing about it. What makes an addon compatible?

Comment: What compatible issue do you encounter exactly? Do you mean the addon doesn't work when EPM is enabled? Is there any error showing when you run the addon? Please clarify the issue more detailly so that we can have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. Second, the error message says, the addon is not compatible witj EPM so it is not allowed to run. When I install it on another machine where EPM is turned off the IE11 accepts the addon. Otherwise I took the code from here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w

Answer (score 0):

Which version is your addon is? 32-bit or 64-bit? EPM only allows 64-bit addons to run, so you need to generate a 64-bit version of addon if you want to use it in EPM. For more information, you can refer to [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e95d4a20-2adf-48a4-a7b4-e8697dd5bc64/how-to-make-32bitonly-addons-work-with-windows-7-internet-explorer-11-and-enhanced-protected?forum=ieitprocurrentver).

Besides, Enhanced Protected Mode isolates untrusted web content in a restricted environment that's known as an **AppContainer**. This process limits how much access malware, spyware, or other potentially harmful code has to your system. So you need to place your addon's DLL with an AppContainer-readable folder (e.g. a subfolder of the \Program Files\ folder). For more information, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570827/ie-bho-in-epm-enhanced-protected-mode) and [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/enhanced-protected-mode-add-on-compatibility#introduction).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created both 32 and 64 bit addons and I put them in Program Files and Program Files (x86) folders. My colleague enabled it in Group Policy buth nothing. At the end we had to turn off EPM and it solved our problem. The addon works.